# Doctrine2: Type x already exists

Tags: api, types, doctrine

I have a problem with the Doctrine API.

I want to add a new Doctrine Type. I followed this documentation to create the class, and I have added the type in my custom driver.

```
Type::addType("custom", "Namespace\NameBundle\Types\CustomType");
$this->registerDoctrineTypeMapping("CustomType", "custom");
```

My problem append when I execute php app/console cache:clear.

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
Type custom already exists.
```

After few searches, I have found in Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(…) throw an exception if the type is knew… I don't understand why this error is throwing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have found my problem !

I don't know why, but my custom type is loading again and again.

To resolve this problem, adding this code like checking.

```
if (!Type::hasType("custom")) {
    Type::addType("custom", "Namespace\NameBundle\Types\CustomType");
    $this->registerDoctrineTypeMapping("CustomType", "custom");
}
```

It works !

Comment: Thanks! Helped me too)