# Symfony 3.3 + Doctrine/MongoDB: Register custom mapping type

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-odm

Since Symfony 3.3 the file *app/autoload.php* disappeared. But I used it to register a custom mapping type as described [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#custom-mapping-types).

My current *app/autoload.php* looks like this:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Types\Type;

/** @var ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

Type::addType("MyCustomType", "Com\\MyBundle\\Db\\MyCustomTypeClass");
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader([$loader, 'loadClass']);
AnnotationDriver::registerAnnotationClasses();

return $loader;
```

As stated [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html#register-the-annotations-and-the-bundle), `AnnotationDriver::registerAnnotationClasses();`doesn't need to be called any longer with Symfony 3.3. But I don't know, where to put

```
Type::addType("MyCustomType", "Com\\MyBundle\\Db\\MyCustomTypeClass");
```

I tried to put it into the `boot()` method of `MyBundle` class which extends `Bundle`. But when I execute my unit tests for the first time after having applied the change, I get `InvalidArgumentException: Invalid type specified "MyCustomType".`. When I execute them again, I get `Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\MappingException: Type MyCustomType already exists.`.

Answer (score 0):

As referenced on the official documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            my_custom_type:  Com\\MyBundle\\Db\\MyCustomTypeClass
```

Comment: I am using Doctrine-**ODM** (for MongoDB), not Doctrine-ORM. You are linking to the Doctrine-ORM manual. The configuration you are showing only applies to Doctrine-ORM. The configuration for Doctrine-ODM starts with: `doctrine_mongodb:`. Unfortunately, it hasn't the `dbal:` configuration option.

Comment: You're absolutely right; my mistake! Have you tried loading it in your `__construct()` method within your `MyBundle` class file?

Comment: I tried putting the `Type::addType` code into `__construct()` instead of `boot()` as well, but it had the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20900499/715660). Although this solution is for Doctrine-ORM, it also works for Doctrine-ODM (Doctrine/MongoDB).

It uses the same approach that I tried first: to put the `Type::addType` call into the `boot()` method of the Bundle class. However, it checks first if the type already exists:

```
public function boot() {
    if(!Type::hasType("MyCustomType")) {
        Type::addType("MyCustomType", "Com\\MyBundle\\Db\\MyCustomTypeClass");
    }
}
```

This works, though I'm not sure, if it is the most elegant solution.

**Edit:**

Though it seemed to work (unit tests are working) it does not run on the server. And it seems to have something to do with the Hydrators.

1. The first call to `bin/console server:run` gives an error: `Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Invalid type specified "MyCustomType"`
2. After terminating the server, the restart of the server *does* work.
3. But then browsing to any URL that is mapped to a controller gives again an `(1/1) InvalidArgumentException Invalid type specified "MyCustomType".` (now displayed in the browser).
4. Reloading the URL does work.
5. At this point, the app works, but a restart of the server gives again the problem mentioned at 1.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for the problem you described in the edit? I'm currently going through the same problem